# How many solutions does this system of equations have?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, real-numbers

I have $2$ equations :

> $$-\frac{a}{2}x-\frac{b}{2}+cx+d=x+2$$
>   $$-2ax-2b+cx+d=2x+1$$
>   with $a, b, c, x \neq 0$

We have to find all possible solutions of $a, b, c, d$ that make the equations true for all $x$.

I found one solution
$a=-\frac{2}{3}$, 
$b=\frac{2}{3}$, 
$c=\frac{2}{3}$, 
$d=\frac{7}{3}$

But, I wonder if there are any other solutions to this system of equations?

Comment: You have two equations and 5 unknowns. Your system is not determined, which means there is an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: The phrase "for any $x$" is ambiguous.  It might mean you want to find $a,b,c,d$ as functions of $x$, or it might mean you want to find $a,b,c,d$ that make the equations true for all $x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the equations as:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
(a-2c+2)x+b-2d+4 = 0 \\
(2a-c+2)x+2b-d+1 = 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

A polynomial is identical $0$ (i.e. for all $x$) iff all its coefficients are $0\,$, which gives the system to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a - 2c + 2 = 0 \\
2a - c + 2 = 0 \\[7px]
b - 2d + 4 = 0 \\
2b -d + 1 = 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

The system has the unique solution as posted $\;a=-\frac{2}{3}$, $b=\frac{2}{3}$, $c=\frac{2}{3}$, $d=\frac{7}{3}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Your $2\times 2$ system is consisted of $5$ variables (unknowns) to which you're being asked to find the solutions. Since you have only two equations for $5$ unknowns, this means that there is an infinite number of solutions (infinite number of numbers $a,b,c,d,x$ that satisfy the system given).

Comment: I little edited the question, I want to find all solutions $a, b, c, d$ for any $x$. Are there still be infinite number of solutions? Could you add one example of solution?

Comment: @Snip3r Yes. Try solving one with respect to $x$ and plugging it down. You'll notice it !